# Transformations for extremely skewed data for Binary Logistic Regression

Tags: regression, machine-learning, logistic, data-transformation

Good evening everyone,

I have a dataset with 5000 observations, and 10 explanatory and 1 response variable (binary 0 or 1), and my task is to make a logistic regression model that can ideally predict well as well as help understand the situation and which variables are most impactful (so not a black box).

All of the variables are extremely skewed, although in theory this should not be much of an issue for logistic regression, throughout my EDA and preprocessing stage (analyzing + imputing missing values) I relied on transformations to visualize the data, because without them the plots are practically unreadable. After fitting an initial model and looking at residual plots, and putting transformed variables into the model (as suggested in Simon J. Sheather "A Modern Approach to Regression with R") the transformed terms are far more impactful and significant, showing that so far there is overwhelming evidence in favor of implementing transformation for predictors.

**TLDR**

****My question is as follows**, for variables that have zero values and/or negative values as well as positive ones, what are the best transformations?** From bestNormalize package in R, the suggested transformations were  orderNorm (ORQ), Yeo-Johnson and arcsinh(x). In cases where there is a very small negative value present, or only zero+positive ones sqrt(x + a) and Log_b(x+a) were suggested too (adding a constant to make values positive, then apply log/sqrt). I am completely unfamiliar with orderNorm and Yeo-Johnson, and want to ask about any **theoretical implications or drawbacks** about using them.

Comment: There's no answer to this, because "best transformations" depends on all the variables and the model.  Moreover, there are arbitrarily many transformations one might select from.  You can read about Yeo-Johnson and sinh by searching our site.  "OrderNorm" is not really a transformation so much as a way of modifying the data, because it is too flexible to generalize to unsampled values.  The "zero+positive" transformations were called "started" transformations by John Tukey; again, you can find much about them here: try https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/30728 *inter alia.*

Comment: BTW, this reads like a duplicate of [your previous question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/643361/919).

Comment: I wouldn't say its a duplicate, the question is almost the same yes, but I believed it to be resolved since a few people said transformations are unnecessary. Unfortunately I found that without them it is virtually impossible to do any decent analysis from graphs/plots because the scale only accommodates the outliers. Since the problem still persists I decided to post an updates question, more aimed at this concern.